Playing Video in GTK4 Window using GTKVideo
I am using GTK4 Application. For that I need to play video in GTK Window using GtkVideo. For that I have created a sample application in C. Here I am attaching the code regarding to it:
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *video;
 
    // Create the main application window
    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK4 Video Player");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 600);
 
    // Create a GtkVideo widget
    video = gtk_video_new();
    // Load a video file
    gtk_video_set_file(GTK_VIDEO(video), g_file_new_for_path("my_video.mp4"));
 
    // Add the video widget to the window
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), video);
 
    // Show all widgets in the window
    gtk_widget_show(window);
 
    // Start playing the video
    gtk_media_stream_play(GTK_MEDIA_STREAM(video));
 
    // Run the GTK main loop
 
    return 0;
}
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;
    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);
 
    return status;
}

For the above code, I am getting a blank screen, but I can't play the video in the GTK Window. Here I am attaching the snap regarding to it:

Can anyone suggest me how to play the video in the GTK4 Window or any other alternative methods to play video in Gtkwindow is highly appreciable.

I was able to make the program work as follows:

The string must be encoded in the glib filename encoding.
GtkVideo is the widget that plays the video.
Start the video with "autoplay".

I also updated the program somewhat.
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *video;


    // Create the main application window
    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK4 Video Player");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 600);

    // Create a GtkVideo widget
    video = gtk_video_new();
    const char *utf8Filename = "my_video.mp4";
    gchar *glibEncodedFilename = g_filename_from_utf8(utf8Filename, -1, NULL,NULL,NULL);
      // Load a video file
    gtk_video_set_file(GTK_VIDEO(video), g_file_new_for_path(glibEncodedFilename));
    // start the video if visible
    gtk_video_set_autoplay(GTK_VIDEO(video),TRUE);
    // Add the video widget to the window
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), video);

    // Show all widgets in the window
    gtk_widget_set_visible(window,TRUE);

    //return 0;Return value of the function is "void"

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;
    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS); 
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}

It is important to make sure that your operating system has the appropriate codex. The video must be also played in this way.
